# Number of Children in Wrapper Chosen by Sorting Script

Tags: jquery, children

```
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.hasClass('To_A') ? '#Section_A'
               : $this.hasClass('To_B') ? '#Section_B'
               : $this.hasClass('To_C') ? '#Section_C'
               : null;

    var XofField = ($(target).length()) * 88;
```

I have a script that moves an element to a specific place in the DOM based on it's class. I need to know how many children are already in that target location, for the purpose of a css left property.

The last line of the above code does not work. Since the location varies, i felt that using target would be convenient.

*Should count new children that are created dynamically.

*SOLUTION*

var sectCount = $(target + " img").length;

Looking back i realize how simple the solution actually was... -__-"

Answer (score 1):

`length` is a property, not a method.  Also, you want children.

`$(target).children().length`

Comment: It works in that it counts children that are already part of the DOM on pageload. It doesn't count new children that are dynamically created, which is paramount.

Comment: It will count all children within that element at the time the code is run.  This is DIRECT children.  If you need to count nested children or something like that you will probably need `find` instead of `children`

Comment: It doesn't appear to, i'll see if i can't reproduce via a fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, so that's not really counting children, it counts all images regardless of level of nesting

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$(target).children().length * 88;` instead